# Textbox moves according to column header selected in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` which has some columns like `Date, Description , Module, Name` etc.Below of that `Datagridview` I have a Textbox and label(Search) which is used for searching the value of selected column.

My problem is that, I want to move the label (Search) and Textbox according to  selected column.For example if I select Description column , the label (Search)  should be in Date column and Textbox should be in Description column and  textbox width should be same as column width.If I select zero index column (Date) the Textbox should be in Date column and the Label(Search) at first index column.

I am stuck in this problem and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How do you select your column? Click on the column header or some radiobutton above (and outside) the column?

Comment: Ya click on the column header.

Comment: don't fix the text box and search label, make them dynamic...... as you will be fixing the starting point of Datagridview... now you need to write one function that will work while selecting the columns....
now as per column selected place the dynamic search label and text box corresponding to that columns....
if the width of the column is dynamic then get the value and append it in the text box and label width...... 
suppose you want to move the textbox and label to rows then solution is to get the height of row and count number of rows you will get exact position...
try this logic...

Comment: Can you please give an example code?

Comment: yaar,i told you the logic..code you need to write... if you are facing any problem in logic then let me know... if this logic helps you then upvote it... 
or more better solution you come across please post it...so that it will help others also..

Comment: i posted one sample code which i implemented in my project... here on button click event i am moving some text box,datagridview to down on each button click....

Answer (score 1):

I am posting one sample code which i implemented in my project... here on button click event i am moving some text box,datagridview to down on each button click...same way you make your search textbox and label location dynamic...
for example..suppose your first column(Date) is starting at location 10,20 then on selecting **description** column set the location of label to (10,20) ..same way proceed for other options...

see below code might it will give some idea...

```
public  void btn_add_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {

            if (sender == btn_mc_add)
            {

                dgv_mc.Rows.Add();
                int count = dgv_mc.Rows[0].Height;
                int count1 = dgv_mc.Rows.Count;
                k = k + count;
                GBOX_MC.Height = count * count1 + 44;
                dgv_mc.Height = count * count1 + 44;
                GBOX_MW.Location = new Point(5, 141 + k - 44);
                lbl_mw.Location = new Point(6, 90 + k - 22);
                btn_mw_add.Location = new Point(700, (90 + k - 22));
                btn_mw_delete.Location = new Point(770, (90 + k - 22));
                GBOX_SCROLL_NOW.Location = new Point(5, 210 + k + l + 22);
                lbl_scroll_now.Location = new Point(6, 185 + k + l + 22);
                btn_scroll_now_add.Location = new Point(700, 185 + k + l + 22);
                btn_scroll_now_delete.Location = new Point(770, 185 + k + l + 22);

            }


            else if (sender == btn_mw_add)
            {
                dgv_mw.Rows.Add();
                int count = dgv_mw.Rows[0].Height;
                int count1 = dgv_mw.Rows.Count;
                l = l + count;
                GBOX_MW.Height = count * count1 + 44;
                dgv_mw.Height = count * count1 + 44;
                GBOX_SCROLL_NOW.Location = new Point(5, 210 + l + k);
                lbl_scroll_now.Location = new Point(6, 185 + l + k);
                btn_scroll_now_add.Location = new Point(700, 185 + l + k);
                btn_scroll_now_delete.Location = new Point(770, 185 + l + k);
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the search(textbox) and label you should get the location of the selected cell and update the location of both the textbox and label with the new location. You can use the **ContentBounds** for getting the location(coordinates).Also checkout :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.contentbounds(v=vs.110).aspx
Hope this helps